# Huge file size using PdfStamper

Tags: c#, itext

I use iTextSharp to extract one page from a document.
The original document has a size of  1.1 MiB and has 74 pages.
When I extract only one page, then the resulting PDF has a size of 1.2 MiB.

I use this code:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (PdfReader readerTemp = new PdfReader(btFile))
    {                                        
        readerTemp.SelectPages(new int[] {1});
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(readerTemp, ms))
                                    { }
    }
    bt = ms.ToArray();
}
```

I tried also [Jay R answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546335/itextsharp-selectpages-method-flattening-form) with the same result.

Why is the file size so huge?

-- EDIT -- 
I tried this too with exactly the same result :

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (PdfReader readerTemp = new PdfReader(btFile))
    {
        reader.SetPageContent(1, reader.GetPageContent(1), PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION, true);
        readerTemp.SelectPages(new int[] {1});
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(readerTemp, ms, PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5))
        {
            stamper.SetFullCompression();
        }
}
```

Comment: By "weight", do you mean file size? Your current question title reads like a spam advertisement...

Comment: Also, the rest of the non-French speaking world uses "megabytes" instead of "megaoctets".

Comment: I suspect that the resources are shared by all the pages, extracting a single page will get all the baggage. Please show us the PDF.

Comment: @PauloSoares Unfortunatly, I can't. it's an invoice with a lot of clients data

Comment: Consider setting maximum compression for the stamper.

Comment: @mkl Do you have an example to do so ?

Comment: @mkl I've tried with no results....

Comment: Without the PDF in question I don't see how to help you beyond pure guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine a 3000 KB document with ten pages and the following objects:

- four font subsets used on every page, each about 50 KB
- ten images that figure on a single page, each about 200 KB (one image per page)
- four images that figure on every page, each about 50 KB
- ten pages with content streams of about 25 KB each
- about 350 KB for objects such as the catalog, the info dictionary, the page tree, the cross-reference table, etc...

A single page will need at least:
- the four font subsets: 4 times 50 KB
- the single image: 1 time 200 KB
- the four images: 4 times 50 KB
- a single content stream: 1 time 50 KB
- a slightly reduced cross-reference table, a slightly reduced page tree, an almost identical catalog, an info dictionary of identical size,... 200 KB

Together that's 850 KB. This means that you end up with 8500 KB (10 times 850 KB) if you split up a 10-page 3000 KB PDF document into 10 separate pages.

**In your case,** the shared resources are huge. I assume that you have an invoice that was created using a scanned image that acts as the background of each page. That scanned background determines the bulk of the file size.

The file size of a 1-page document can be higher than the file size of a document with multiple pages if the 1-page document doesn't use compressed objects / a compressed xref table, whereas the document with multiple pages does. You can compress objects and the xref table by introducing `stamper.SetFullCompression();`

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. I tried this but with no result. Please see my Edit.

Comment: My explanation explains why the result you are getting isn't the result you want. All pages have a resource in common that is responsible for the bulk of the file size.

Comment: My bad. I thought that your last line was my solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
        stamper.SetFullCompression();
```

to reduce file size.

Comment: Thanks but it don't work at all... Please see my Edit.